# Meteor HTTP.call() Authorization Header

Tags: meteor, oauth

I'm developing a new `accounts-***` package for an API which uses an authorization header rather than an `access_token` parameter (as is done by most other APIs/packages I've seen). However, every version I've attempted has resulted in a 401 being returned. I've tried a few variations to no avail (Authorization in quotes/without quotes, declaring the accessToken as a new variable inside the funtion, etc.). Am I missing something obvious?

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////
// packages/newApi/newApi_server.js
////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Other steps for exchanging auth code for access and refresh tokens
var getIdentity = function(accessToken){
  var accessTokenString = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
  try {
    return HTTP.get("https://testapi.testing.com/user/info", {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': accessTokenString
      }
    }).data;
  } catch(err) {
    throw_.extend(new Error('You done goofed. ' + err.message));
  }
};
```

**Edit:** I had tried securing my accessToken earlier in the OAuth flow which was breaking the identity fetching.

Comment: why do you have single quotes around 'accessTokeString'? Also, you have a space after 'Bearer ' - is that supposed to be there? In my experience with API's that would usually cause an error.

Comment: @RamsayLanier the quotes were a transposition error on my part; as for the space after bearer, it seems to be correct. Here's the example given by the docs: "curl --include \
     --header "Authorization: Bearer example_access_token_like_135fhn80w35hynainrsg0q824hyn" "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explained in the edit, it was a silly encoding/encryption mistake. Make sure your access tokens are properly accessible.